# Send periodic information/messages to Android app

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have a simple Android app that accesses data (XML) from a Visual Studio web service.

I would like to send data to the Android app at various intervals with the web service initiating the communication that is not as a response.

Without using an RSS feed, how would the web service know where the data is to be sent and how would this be implemented?

How would the android up be set up to expect and receive this data

Comment: The webservice can't initiate the connection to the device. It must be the device that starts the connection. But you could have a look at http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/c2dm/ maybe

Comment: Is it possible then that the Android device contacts the web service one time and data is stored by the web service and later reused to contact the android app?

Comment: The webservice can't establish a connection to the device because even if it has the IP adress of the device it will be stopped by firewalls and the like. You would have to make the device keep a connection to your webservice open. But then it's easier to have the device poll an RSS feed every X minutes.

Comment: ok. thanks alot. I have to try polling then, but it mite be highly inefficient as the data is extremely sporadic, being triggered by events on the webservice

Comment: did you took a look at my links? it actually pushes some information to your app. and then the app can download the data

Comment: @JeanLuc. Thanks alot. I did look at the link but from what I say the user would need to have a Google account to utilize the cloud to device. Am i right? If so it mite not be suitable for my application.

Comment: yes, that right, so i guess you are not targetting google play (a.ka. android market)

Answer (score 2):

if you're targeting android 2.2 and higher, you can take at look at this [Android Cloud To Device Messaging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html)